# Is it a correct conditional sentence?

Tags: conditional-constructions, conditionals

Today I read the following sentence in the newspaper:

"If you have noticed boys who play gully cricket, you would have figured out how they...."

Now I have to ask:

1. Is it a correct conditional sentence. If yes, which conditional type?
2. Is it a mixed conditional sentence?
3. If it's incorrect, what is the correct form for the same expression of idea?

Comment: The sentence is a mixture, so it's not clear what you want to say. Are you talking about something that could happen, or a hyporthetical situation that could never happen?

Comment: @JavaLatte I'm not talking anything. I read the sentence in the newspaper. My question is a simple one: is it a correct conditional sentence? Please respond if only you can understand the question. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't correct; there is an inconsistency in the use of tenses. It should be EITHER "If you have noticed... you *will* have figured out"

OR "If you *had* noticed... you would have figured out".

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had similar ideas, but wanted to confirm with someone competent.